# Sending email using vb.net with CC and BCC

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

This is a code snippet for sending email using vb.net:

```vb
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New _
        Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password")
            SmtpServer.Port = 587
            SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress("YOURusername@gmail.com")
            mail.To.Add("TOADDRESS")
            mail.Subject = "Test Mail"
            mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL"
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("mail send")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can I add CC and BCC address too? If yes, what are the possible codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
e_mail.CC.Add("user@domain.com")
e_mail.Bcc.Add("user@domain.com")
```

Got it from myself :)

Comment: A recommendation for the future: Googling and/or investigating the classes you're working with should go before posting a question.

Comment: Oh.. Thank you :)